# Force layout nodes filled with images

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm struggling with images integration in my nodes, despite trying to follow [the labeled force layout example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642).

The following code is the index.html page. 
You'll find a `var dataset` in it which contains an example of data I will use. I made the changes I considered appropriate for having this code to work, but it basically breaks my viz.

If the content of `var node` is changed to `"circle"`, then I've got a satisfying rendering of the circles. I could live with it, but I'd really like to fill the circles with images. (the image prop is here the Github icon, nothing original!)

Any help will be, as usual, much appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>d3</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #E7E7E7;
    }
    line{
    stroke: #aaa;
    stroke-width: 2;
    }
    circle{
/*    fill: #1a1a1a;
*/    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 4;
    opacity: 0.9;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
  window.onload = function(){
  var w = 1000,
      h = 500;
  var svg = d3.select("#svgContent")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", w)
                  .attr("height", h)
                  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin slice')
                  .append('g');
  var dataSet = {
      nodes: [
              { name: "Sara", id:"1", x:500, y:250, fixed:true, doge:1, img:"https://github.com/favicon.ico"},
              { name: "Raul", id:"2", fixed:false, doge:5},
              { name: "Stefano", id:"3", fixed:false, doge:5},
              { name: "Michele", id:"4", fixed:false, doge:1},
              { name: "Frank", id:"5", fixed:false, doge:1},
              { name: "Luc", id: "6", fixed:false, doge:2},
              { name: "Laurent", id: "7", fixed:false, doge:4},
              { name: "Sachiko", id: "8", fixed:false, doge:0},
              { name: "Minn", id: "9", fixed:false, doge:0},
              { name: "Basile", id: "10", fixed:false, doge:2},
              { name: "Doge", id: "11", fixed:false, doge:0},
              { name: "Laurent", id: "12", fixed:false, doge:4},
              { name: "Master", id: "13", fixed:false, doge:7, img:"https://github.com/favicon.ico"},
              { name: "Boulet", id: "14", fixed:false, doge:0},
              { name: "Why", id: "15", fixed:false, doge:2},
              { name: "Bit", id: "16", fixed:false, doge:0},
              { name: "Moi", id: "17", fixed:false, doge:1},
              { name: "Lui", id: "18", fixed:false, doge:10},
              { name: "Elle", id: "19", fixed:false, doge:0},
              { name: "Coin", id: "20", fixed:false, doge:2},
      ],
      edges: [
              { source: 0, target: 1 },{ source: 1, target: 0 },
              { source: 0, target: 9 },{ source: 9, target: 0 },
              { source: 0, target: 12 },{ source: 12, target: 0 },
              { source: 0, target: 16 },{ source: 16, target: 0 }
      ]
    };

    var force = self.force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(dataSet.nodes)
      .links(dataSet.edges)
      .linkStrength(0.5)
      .gravity(0.1)
            .distance(120)
            .charge(-300)
      .size([w,h])
      .start();

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(dataSet.edges)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    var node_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .on("dragstart", dragstart)
      .on("drag", dragmove)
      .on("dragend", dragend);

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(dataSet.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      // .attr("r", function(d) {return d.doge*5})
      .call(node_drag);

  node.append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0)
      .attr("width", 16)
      .attr("height", 16);

    d3.select("#svgContent")
      .selectAll('circle')
        .on('mouseover', function(d){
            d3.select(this)
              .transition().attr('r', function(d) {return d.doge*6})
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d){
            d3.select(this)
              .transition().attr('r', function(d) {return d.doge*5})
        })

    function dragstart(d, i) {
      force.stop(); // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
    }

    function dragmove(d, i) {
      d.px += d3.event.dx;
      d.py += d3.event.dy;
      d.x += d3.event.dx;
      d.y += d3.event.dy;
      tick();
    }

    function dragend(d, i) {
      d.fixed = true; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
      tick();
      force.resume();
    }

    force.on("tick", tick);

    function tick() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
          }
};

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="svgContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just need to adapt the code to change the position of the node elements. Is this what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/5acQ4/

Comment: It works perfectly. Can you just explain a bit the changes you made? I wonder if you're doing something else that helping strangers all day - thank you for that.

Comment: Great, I'll add this as an answer with some explanations.

Comment: @user3041647 Lars, who is really an artificial intelligence wiz, has managed to clone himself as part of one his experiments. So, actually, what we interact with on a daily basis here in this SO group is his clone...into which he implanted only half his intellectual capacity since more of it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you're missing is that for `g` elements, setting `cx`/`cy` doesn't do anything. That is, the code

```
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

in your `tick()` function works fine for circles (which have `cx`/`cy`), but not for `g` elements. What you need to set there is `transform`:

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

Apart from that, you just need to adjust the positions of the icons like in the example you've linked to so that they appear centred. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5acQ4/).